# problemas para imprimir una lista //[<__main__.Personas object at 0x0000029EC2963D00>]

Tags: python, python-3.x

este es mi codigo el cual estoy tratando de imprimir una lista que esta en un objeto pero me da un tipo de mensaje [<**main**.Personas object at 0x0000029EC2963D00>]`

```
import pickle



class Personas():
    def __init__(self,nombre,genero,edad):
        self.nombre=edad
        self.genero=genero
        self.edad=edad


    def __str__(self):
        print("el nombre es {} su genero es y tiene {} de 
edad".format(self.nombre,self.genero,self.edad))


class Guardado:
    lista=[]

    def Escritura(self,p):
        self.nombre = open("Usuario","wb")
        self.lista.append(p)
        print(self.lista)

sub=Personas("juan","masculino","22")
x=Guardado()
x.Escritura(sub)
```

Salida

[<**main**.Personas object at 0x0000029EC2963D00>]
[Finished in 500ms]

les agradecería si me pueden ayudar

Comment: Eso es lo normal, no hay error alguno. Que quieres que se muestre?

Comment: quiero que agregue los valores a la a la lista y me imprima esa misma lista

Comment: Tienes que implementar el dunder method `__repr__` y en este retirnar la lista que deseas

Comment: @TECNOGCODER ahí te deje una respuesta no se si es eso lo que buscas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando estas imprimiendo la lista te muestra la lista y el id de cada elemento que tiene, para solucionar eso podemos hacer uso del método especial `__repr__`

( si usas un for para recorrer la lista te debería mostrar cada elemento sin ningún problema )

algo así:

```
class Persona(object):
    def __init__(self, id , nombre) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.id} {self.nombre}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str: # este método
        return f"{self.id} {self.nombre}"
```

.

```
lista = []
p = Persona(1, "Persona")
lista.append(p)

print(lista)
```

resultado

```
>>> [1, Persona]
```

aquí mas [info](https://jarroba.com/repr-y-str-de-python/)

Comment: me sirvo el bulce for , el metodo __repr__ no fue necesario pero me sirvio para otros proyectos